# How to access the sort query in nodejs from react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, frontend, backend

I'm building a simple project and I want to get a sorted listed from nodejs. Below my nodejs code

```
import User from ...
const getAllUserStatic = asyncHandler(async(req,res)=>{
     const {name, sort, field} = req.query
     const queryObject = {}
     
     if(name){
         queryObject.name = name
     }
     const result = User.find({})
     if(sort){
         const sortList = sort.split(',').join(' ')
         result = result.sort(sortList)   
     }

     const user = await result
})
```

the codes work well in postman However, I am trying to access this from React, but not getting a result. below is my code from react

```
import axios from 'axios'
const handleSort = async()=>{
   try{
      const {data} = await axios.get('/api/user/static?sort=name') 
      console.log(data)
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `result` in your code (the return value of `User.find({})`)?

Comment: a whole lot of information which seems unreadeble until the await was added below.

Comment: Hmm. That "whole lot of information" is called a `"Promise"` object. When you call `await`, it's resolved to whatever data it should be resolved to, or rejected with any relevant error.

Answer (score 0):

`axios.get()` returns a **"Promise"**. So you need to resolve it. Below code should work.

```js
const handleSort = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/user/static?sort=name') 
    console.log(data)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: oops, I forgot to include await when I typed it here. But that still didn't fix it. I think the issue is what will be in await axios.get('  HERE ')

Comment: Is there any error shown in the console? Any HTTP `4xx` error? Anything else?

Comment: I got undefined when I logged ```data```

Comment: Does it return `200` status?

Comment: No, just undefined. that's what disturbs me.

Comment: If it's not `200`, it must be one of `4xx` errors. You need to check that before we proceed to any solution.

Comment: Ok I added ```.then(response=>console.log(response.data))``` and I got a ```Request failed with status code 500``` name ```AxiosError```

Comment: `500` means server error. Check the console of your Node.js app.

Comment: thanks a lot. I have seen my error. I spelled ```static``` as ```staic```

Comment: Great to hear that. Happy coding.